# xamarin grid set row height

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, grid

I need to set the grid row height.

please see blow is my grid

```
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <!--<ToolbarItem Text="Logout" Clicked="OnLogout_Clicked" />-->

    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>


    <ContentPage.Content>

        <ScrollView>

            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="MediumPurple"  >
                <!--<Button Text="Sign Out" Clicked="Signout_Clicked" FontAttributes="Bold"  BackgroundColor="MediumSlateBlue" BorderRadius="5" TextColor="White"></Button>-->

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White">

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Button Text="All" Clicked="All_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Orange"   />
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Button Text="A" Clicked="A_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Orange" />
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Button Text="B" Clicked="B_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Orange"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Button Text="C" Clicked="C_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Orange"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>
                <Label Text="msg" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Label x:Name="lblMsg" TextColor="Red"  IsVisible="False" ></Label>



                <ListView x:Name="listView"   ItemTapped="OnItemSelected"  BackgroundColor="MediumPurple" >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate  >
                            <ViewCell >

                                <Grid Padding="5">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90"  ></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="ID" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"  TextColor="Black"></Label>
                                    <Label BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="End" Text="Description Text Description Text Description Text Description Text Description Text Description Text " Font="Small"  TextColor="Black" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  ></Label>
                                    <Label BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Date"   TextColor="Black"></Label>

                                </Grid>

                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>


        </ScrollView>




    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

I need to set height to `Description` .because Description  is cropped.
How do I show the whole Description  ?

[image]

I need something like above table.

Comment: Have you tried by setting row height to `Auto`, like `<RowDefinition  Height="Auto"   />`?

Comment: and why are you using `Grid.RowSpan="2"` for `Description`, instead you should use `ColumnSpan`because for Row 1 - Column 1, there is no control.

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: Have you removed `Grid.RowSpan="2"` and replaced height with `Auto`?Also remove `HeightRequest="90"` and add `HorizontalOptions=FillAndExpand`, in that case it should be working.

Comment: also remove `Grid.RowSpan="3"` `WidthRequest="33"`, I have posted code below, you can check that out, if it might helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate  >
                    <ViewCell >

                        <Grid Padding="5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"  ></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="ID" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"  TextColor="Black"></Label>
                            <Label BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Description Text Description Text Description Text Description Text Description Text Description Text " Font="Small"  TextColor="Black" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"  ></Label>
                            <Label BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Date"   TextColor="Black"></Label>

                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

[image: Screen Shot for the same is attached]

Comment: @user1348351 I have tried to solve this issue and modified code as well, have edited my answer by latest code and screen shot for the same, hope this may solve your issue.

Comment: @user1348351 just set `HasUnevenRows="True"` in your List view tag, it will now work fine, the issue was row height of list view.